# Laravel : relations are not working in every ways of the request

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Given two tables :

```
Package
--------
int id
int parcel_id
int order_id
timestamps()

Order
--------
int id
int user_id
int search_id
timestamp shipping_date
timestamps()
```

There are one or many `Package` objects which belongs to an `Order`,

Respectively, one `Order` object has one or many `Package` objects.

**Package Model :**

```
public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
public function parcel() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Parcel');
}
```

**Order Model :**

```
public function search() {
    $this->belongsTo('App\Search');
}
public function user() {
    $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function packages() {
    $this->hasMany('App\Package');
}
```

**Question :**

I succeed to get the `Order` of the `Package` but I can't get the `Packages` associated with an `Order`. Why is that ?

I do have the same behaviour the other way around, this time from User, finding the belonging Search.

Search works correctly when I try to find the Search->user.

I have the exact same Model structure with `User` has_many `Adresses`, and `Address` belongs to `User`, which works well in both ways.

My guess is that it's because there are many keys involved into both tables, but I still give the column name into the belongTo/hasMany attribute and *if I recall correctly,* Eloquent relations are based on column and table names, not on the "real" MySQL relations (foreign keys, etc).

**Illustration in php artisan tinker :**

```
>>> $package = App\Package::where('id', 224)->first()
=> App\Package {#800
     id: 224,
     parcel_id: 2,
     weight: 10,
     created_at: "2016-12-29 14:00:58",
     updated_at: "2016-12-29 14:00:58",
     order_id: 115,
   }
>>> $package->order
=> App\Order {#743
     id: 115,
     user_id: 1,
     search_id: 1,
     created_at: "2016-12-29 14:00:58",
     updated_at: "2016-12-29 14:00:58",
     shipping_date: "2016-12-29 14:00:58",
   }
>>> $order = App\Order::where('id', 115)->first()
=> App\Order {#804
     id: 115,
     user_id: 1,
     search_id: 1,
     created_at: "2016-12-29 14:00:58",
     updated_at: "2016-12-29 14:00:58",
     shipping_date: "2016-12-29 14:00:58",
   }
>>> $order->packages
LogicException with message 'Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation'
>>> $order->packages()
=> null
```

Comment: Ok, there no `return` keyword. My bad, problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a return statement on your Order model.

```
public function search() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Search');
}
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function packages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Package');
}
```

You were returning `void` which is not a laravel relationship. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. I was 100% sure that I've haven't missed it after reading similar questions... it occured to me when reading my SO post ! Dealing with a lot of similar files can sometimes be overwhelming without enough caffeine.